# LM358P doesnt respond to inputs

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet-driver, current-limiting

I am currently building a Li-ion cell capacity tester. The circuit has two parts, one that charges the cell, and one that discharges it, but I have removed the charging components to make the circuit easier to read (I can add them if needed).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSmpcc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transistor is there to stop the discharging but when I tested I just pulled it to ground. The 12 V rail comes from a PC PSU. The 0.1 V at the non-inverting input comes from a voltage divider. Datasheets: [op-amp](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358b.pdf), [MOSFET](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRF3205-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355def244190a), [transistor](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/p2n2222a-d.pdf).

So here's the problem: when I connect the battery the op-amp output doesn't react at all. With no battery it's at max voltage (as expected), but it should reduce the output voltage when the inverting input exceeds the non-inverting input voltage.

After frying one shunt I added a 1 Ω power resistor in series with the battery and checked the voltages: output = around 11 V, non-inverting = 0.1 V and inverting = 0.34 V. How is this possible?

I changed the op-amp and got exactly same behavior. I also tested a second op-amp to make sure the pins were in the correct order on the chip and they were.

If someone realizes what I'm missing here or can suggest something I could try please answer.

Edit: circuit redrawn hopefully better.

Comment: Please redraw your circuit using a conventional opamp symbol and sensible layout. As you've currently draw it, it's unnecessarily difficult to interpret for anyone trying to help - and this is probably also contributing to your own problems building and understanding your results.

Comment: What is the purpose of the transistor?  As shown, it does nothing.  Also, add a decoupling cap across the opamp's power pins.  Also, attend to the unused section's input pins.

Comment: @brhans Sorry, i tried redrawing it with the stack exchange circuit designer.

Comment: @AnalogKid As i said in the post, the transistor is there to disable the mosfet in the finished circuit. Since i dont need to stop the discharging i have just pulled it to ground. The other side of the op amp is used by the second cell's discharging circuit. Also thanks, i will add the decoupling cap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown, the body diode conducts in the MOSFET and the gate has little effect. Further, the voltage across the 0.1\$\Omega\$ resistor is then negative, which will destroy the LM358.

It's not really clear what you are trying to do. I might guess it's an attempt at a constant current sink, but for that you will need a reference voltage to determine the current.

---

Edit: Okay now that you've redrawn it and added the 100mV source- the resistor needs to go in the source so that the feedback voltage is positive wrt ground. You have around 10V of drive available so the slight reduction in Vgs is of no consequence.

It's possible this circuit, as drawn, will oscillate without some compensation but it may be okay with an LM358. Hopefully you have an oscilloscope available.

Comment: Sorry the schematic had the mosfet flipped. I have redrawn the circuit. The voltage across the shunt being negative was actually a worry i had but when i built the circuit on breadboard i remember it working and when i measured the voltage (negative probe to ground) it was positive. Could it really be negative? But yes you got it right, its a constant current sink and the 0.1V at the non inverting input is the reference.

Comment: Breadboards are a nightmare of wires all over the place. I made thousands of prototype circuits compact with clear connections neatly soldered on stripboard.

Comment: @Audioguru I agree. The finished circuit is soldered on a protoboard. Before i started soldering though i quickly tried it on a breadboard to make sure i wasnt missing anything basic. Guess it didnt help.

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand what you mean. Which resistor do you mean when saying "the resistor needs to go in the source"? Oh and i do have a very basic oscilloscope available. If you think that can help analyze the problem just instruct me how and i will measure.

Comment: Move R1 to between the source and ground and take the feedback from the source. And parallel the 10K with 100nF.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes! That's it. So the feedback voltage was negative all this time. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You show the Mosfet connected upside down then its diode conducts and causes the opamp inverting input to be negative 11.3V destroying the opamp.

[image: Mosfet]

Comment: Glad you noticed that i messed up drawing the mosfet. However i dont fully understand your answer. The mosfet isnt supposed to be fully turned on. The op amp should output enough voltage at the gate to let 1 amp pass through the mosfet. Could you check the new schematic and explain your answer a bit more?

Comment: If the Mosfet is only half turned on then with a 12V supply and a 0.1 ohm resistor the Mosfet cooks to death with heating that is 360W!

Comment: The mosfet isnt half turned on either. It has just enough voltage at its gate for 1 amp to pass. So it would be 11.9W with a 12V supply. Either way the battery voltage is not 12V, its 4.2V max for my li-ion cells.